# Make Setup File using External Database

Tags: c#, mysql, database, installation

I made an application in C# Windows Form in Visual Studio 2012. That application uses external MySQL database.

I want to make a setup file that also contains the external database.

Comment: The files will not be enough, every user will need to have MySQL installed on their machine.

Comment: ok fine. but is there need for each user to make tables manually on their machines?

Comment: You will need to install the tables usually via a script on each server and then each machine will connect to that server database. You really should supply code and a little structure to your question, this really is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

What would probably be the easiest way to do this is to run mysqldump on your database with the initial data needed, then include that dump file in your project as a text file or an sql file. You would then on startup check to see if the database has been created, and if not read and execute the dump file that is included in your project.